# How do I find which customers purchased content only from a certain author?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the below data that captures customers and the author of the content they purchased. A customer can have many rows of data either by the same or differing authors (each row is unique to a purchase).  I am looking to flag each row to tell me if that customer ONLY purchased content by that specific author.  Put another way that unique customer ID would not appear with another author besides the one in the row being evaluated.

| Customer | Author |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bill |
| 1 | Bill |
| 2 | Bill |
| 3 | Bob |
| 4 | Jim |
| 4 | Jim |
| 4 | Ann |
| 5 | Mike |

What I would like:

| Customer | Author | Unique |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bill | Yes |
| 1 | Bill | Yes |
| 2 | Bill | Yes |
| 3 | Bob | Yes |
| 4 | Jim | No |
| 4 | Jim | No |
| 4 | Ann | No |
| 5 | Mike | Yes |

To clarify above, Customer 1 is being flagged because even though they purchased multiple items, they were both by the same author (Bill), this is not the case for customer 4 as they purchased 2 different authors (Jim and Ann).

Comment: Why is Customer 1 buying two books by Bill Unique but not Customer 4 buying two books by Jim?

Comment: Also, can you include which solutions you have tried so far?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad because Customer 4 also bought a book by Ann. The OP wants to identify single-author purchasers (I think)

Comment: Please clarify the logic required. by editing your question. as @Mig said, what you've tried would also be useful

Comment: Yup what @cybernetic.nomad said.  I'll edit the question.  I've tried a couple of countifs, but with little success.  The only way I've been able to do it was splitting the data into different tabs by author and doing vlookups which I'm then consolidating back in and pivoting.  Not elegant or sustainable given the amount of data I'm dealing with 200k+ rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your version of Excel, you may be able to use the [UNIQUE()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e) and [FILTER()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) functions for this.

In cell `C2`, you can use the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=A2,"")))=1,"Yes","No")
```

and then copy/paste it down. It works by filtering all the values from the Author column where the Customer number is the same, extracting just the unique values from that list, and then counting them. If there's only 1 left, then the customer only every bought from that one author.

In the screenshot below, I've including a column showing the results of the COUNTA() function so you can see an interim step.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: THANK YOU! I think this is going to work!

Answer (score 1):

If I under stand the required logic correctly, the following formula should do it:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)=COUNTIF(A:A,A2),COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>1),"flag","")
```

Note that there are many possible cases that this does not cover, but based on the little information available, this should work